# Is this code correct to create a new object for the parameter to an event?

Tags: c#, events, garbage-collection

I came across the following C# function:

```
    void SomeMethod(List<ISomeInterface> inputObjects)
    {
        IList<ISomeInterface> newListOfObjects = null;

        if (inputObjects != null)
        {
            //create a new list
            newListOfObjects = new List<ISomeInterface>();
            //copy the input parameter into the new list
            foreach (ISomeInterface thing in inputObjects)
            {
                newListOfObjects.Add(thing);
            }
        }
        //send an event to another module with the new list as parameter
        DelegateHandler.AsyncInvoke(this.SomeEvent, newListOfObjects);
    }
```

My questions are: is it necessary to create a object to be the parameter for SomeEvent? What would happen if I just passed inputObjects as the parameter to SomeEvent?
I am guessing that maybe the garbage collector would see no references to inputObjects, and would delete it when SomeMethod is finished.

Comment: This code seems to try to isolate the change made to the list passed to the event from the original input list (adding and removing of objects), so the answer depends on what you are doing with the inputObjects list after the call to SomeMethod

Comment: I agree with Steve. Though I think this method is unnecessary, given that you could just use `new List<ISomeInterface>(inputObjects)` or `inputObjects.ToList()` as the parameter instead.

Comment: Thanks Steve and Ginosaji. I think that is what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to copy the list. The garbage collector will know that the object itself is still in use and it will not be garbage collected.

The difference between passing a copy and the original lies in the fact that if you pass the original, any modifications to the list will also be visible in the calling method whereas otherwise the modifications are only made to the copy

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but the data structures used internally by `AsyncInvoke` will root the object and make sure it isn't collected until `this.SomeEvent` returns (on the other thread).

Answer (score 1):

When you copy the elements from one list to another you keep the same references of the elements inside your original list (if they are of **reference** type).